# Nonuniform Moving of Vertices of Meshes Along Local Normals

Tags: python, vertices, normals

I have a 3D surface with `N` vetrices and `M` faces. I also have independent `numpy` arrays for face normals, `n`, vertices coordinates, `V`, and the triangulation of the vertices in `F`.

For each vertex, I also have a function, `f(iVertex) = h_i` that defines how much the vertex should move along the local normal, which can be outward (positive `h_i` values) or inward (negative `h_i` values). In other words, displacing the vertices along the local normal are not uniform and is different from vertex to vertex according to the function `f(iVertex)`.

The closest solution I found was posted [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/12137/2851). However, I don't want my surface to get disintegrated and I want the faces to remain connected even after displacing the vertices. How can I move the vertices based on `f` *efficiently* in Blender using Python without disassembling the faces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used an existing base mesh to test this, which is why the code I'm using might need some changes for you to be able to implement it.

[image]

The most important thing here is lines 22-23:

```
d    = normal * h_i[i] # Current vertex's displacement value
v.co = V[i] + d        # Displace current vertex along normal
```

You calculate each vertex's new location by adding to it the displacement value, which is the h_i for that vertex X the face normal (which is a direction vector).

Here's the complete code:

```
import bpy, bmesh
import numpy as np

bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh( bpy.context.object.data )

worldMatrix = bpy.context.object.matrix_world

F   = bm.faces                                 # Face objects
V   = [ worldMatrix * v.co for v in bm.verts ] # Vert coordinates

# Generate a random number between -1 and 1 as a displacement value for each vertex
h_i = 2 * np.random.random( len( V ) ) - 1

# Perform displacement
# Iterate over faces (You might want to zip the face normals and triangulations here)
for f in F:
    normal = f.normal # get Face normal (your n value for this face)
    fVerts = f.verts  # List of face vertices (your "F" variable for this face)
    # Iterate over this face's vertices (F[face_index])
    for v in fVerts:
        i = v.index

        d    = normal * h_i[i] # Current vertex's displacement value
        v.co = V[i] + d        # Displace current vertex along normal


update_existing_mesh = True
if update_existing_mesh:
    bm.to_mesh( bpy.context.object.data )
else: # Generate a new mesh
    m = bpy.data.meshes.new( "Displaced" )
    bm.to_mesh( m )

    o = bpy.data.objects.new( "Displaced", m )
    bpy.context.scene.objects.link( o )
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. As a side note, may I know how you recorded your screen for this answer?

Comment: No problem :)
Recorded with: https://screentogif.codeplex.com/

Comment: I noticed that the mesh is not modified and instead a new object is created. Is there any way that instead of creating a new one the current object is displaced and gets modified?

Comment: @Ahmad, I updated the code to present both options